# Ubuntu 14.04.5 Ethernet shot

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I am having an issue with my network configuration. After I executed the command:

```
sudo apt-get purge v4l2loopback*
```

I no longer have any available Ethernet connection after rebooting. The network card by realtek still shows up. Thus far I have tried reinstalling the `network-manager` using a live-USB.

Can you help me out please?

Comment: I don't think I need the purged package to run my Ethernet, do I?

Answer (score 0):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/v4l2loopback contains all the package files.  You can manually reinstall it by downloading the `.deb` that matches your machine architecture, then use

```
sudo dpkg -i <whatever_file_you_downloaded>.deb
```

Comment: I purged that package because it was causing some system errors on startup and I figured I don't need it. Is this package really required to run my Ethernet? I feel like maybe something actually needed was deleted in the process.

Comment: Answers section should contain only answers. You can use Comments to ask for more info or clarification. You can always comment below your posts, but require a minimum reputation points to be able to comment everywhere.